# With a SVG circle, how to position the starting point?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I'm working to create an SVG circle progress indicator in react... Here is my output:

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXRGXw)**

[image]

The problem is I need the red stroke to start at the top, not at the current 90% angle... Is there some CSS I can add to reposition the red stroke to start at the top?

FYI, I'm using the following component in react to render this HTML: https://github.com/wmartins/react-circular-progress/blob/gh-pages/src/js/components/CircularProgress.jsx.js

codepen source below

**html**

```
<svg class="CircularProgress" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
   <circle class="CircularProgress-Bg" cx="25" cy="25" r="24" stroke-width="2px"></circle>
   <circle class="CircularProgress-Fg" cx="25" cy="25" r="24" stroke-width="2px" style="stroke-dasharray: 150.796; stroke-dashoffset: 125.161;"></circle>
   <text class="CircularProgress-Text" x="25" y="25" dy=".4em" text-anchor="middle">17%</text>
</svg>
```

**css**

```
.CircularProgress-Bg,
.CircularProgress-Fg {
    fill: none;
}

.CircularProgress-Bg {
    stroke: #CCC;
}

.CircularProgress-Fg {
    transition: stroke-dashoffset .5s ease-in-out;
    stroke: red;
}

.CircularProgress-Text {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    transform: translate(0 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `transform`, add `transform="rotate(-90 25 25)"` and it will start at the top

```css
.CircularProgress-Bg,
.CircularProgress-Fg {
    fill: none;
}

.CircularProgress-Bg {
    stroke: #CCC;
}

.CircularProgress-Fg {
    transition: stroke-dashoffset .5s ease-in-out;
    stroke: red;
}

.CircularProgress-Text {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    transform: translate(0 50%);
}
```

```html
<svg class="CircularProgress" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">

   <circle class="CircularProgress-Bg" cx="25" cy="25" r="24" stroke-width="2px"></circle>
   <circle transform="rotate(-90 25 25)" class="CircularProgress-Fg" cx="25" cy="25" r="24" stroke-width="2px" style="stroke-startOffest: 50%;stroke-dasharray: 150.796; stroke-dashoffset: 125.161;"></circle>
   <text class="CircularProgress-Text" x="25" y="25" dy=".4em" text-anchor="middle">17%</text>
</svg>
```

---

If to use CSS, you can rotate the `svg` element instead of the `circle` (which might or might not be possible based on its shape)

```css
.CircularProgress {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.CircularProgress-Bg,
.CircularProgress-Fg {
    fill: none;
}

.CircularProgress-Bg {
    stroke: #CCC;
}

.CircularProgress-Fg {
    transition: stroke-dashoffset .5s ease-in-out;
    stroke: red;
}

.CircularProgress-Text {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    transform: translate(0, 50%);
}
```

```html
<svg class="CircularProgress" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
   <circle class="CircularProgress-Bg" cx="25" cy="25" r="24" stroke-width="2px"></circle>
   <circle class="CircularProgress-Fg" cx="25" cy="25" r="24" stroke-width="2px" style="stroke-dasharray: 150.796; stroke-dashoffset: 125.161;"></circle>
   <text class="CircularProgress-Text" x="25" y="25" dy=".4em" text-anchor="middle">17%</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you.I was trying to add via CSS and it wasn't working. I didn't know you could apply it directly to <circle>

Comment: @AnnaSm If to use CSS you need to rotate the `svg` element (which might or might not be possible based on its shape): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgBrGo

Comment: for me working with this value - transform="rotate(180 90 0)"